# Android RxJava Interval with IntentService

Tags: android, service, rx-java

I am quite new to rxjava so I wanted to use it with android IntentService and I need to be notified every second during a certain period (similar to Android CountDownTimer. I have decided to try it with rxjava and I have this class:

```
public class WorkoutService extends IntentService {
public static final String BUNDLE_EXTRA_MESSENGER = "messenger";
public static final String BUNDLE_EXTRA_NUMBER_ROUNDS = "nr_rounds";
public static final String BUNDLE_EXTRA_WORKOUT_DURATION = "workout_duration";
public static final String BUNDLE_EXTRA_PAUSE_DURATION = "pause_duration";
private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
public static final int UPDATE_PROGRESS = 2;

/**
 * Target we publish for clients to send messages to IncomingHandler.
 * This is the messenger from the activity
 */
Messenger messenger;

private NotificationManager notifyManager;
private NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
private volatile int maxProgress;
private int numberOfRounds = 4;
private int workoutDuration = 7 * 60; //7 minutes
private int pauseDuration = 90; //1.5 minutes
private int currentProgress;

public WorkoutService() {
    super("WorkoutService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        messenger = (Messenger) extras.get(BUNDLE_EXTRA_MESSENGER);
        numberOfRounds = extras.getInt(BUNDLE_EXTRA_NUMBER_ROUNDS, numberOfRounds);
        workoutDuration = extras.getInt(BUNDLE_EXTRA_WORKOUT_DURATION, workoutDuration);
        pauseDuration = extras.getInt(BUNDLE_EXTRA_PAUSE_DURATION, pauseDuration);
    }
    maxProgress = numberOfRounds * workoutDuration + ((numberOfRounds - 1) * pauseDuration);
    maxProgress = 10; //TODO: for testing
    showNotification(maxProgress);
    Timber.d("maxProgress %d", maxProgress);
    startWorkout();

}

private void startWorkout() {
    final Observable<Long> observable = Observable
            .interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    observable
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Long>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Timber.d("onCompleted");
                    unsubscribe();
                    stopForeground(true);
                    stopSelf();

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Timber.e("onError");
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Long aLong) {
                    Timber.d("onNext : " + aLong + "S");
                    updateProgress();
                    if (aLong == maxProgress) {
                        onCompleted();
                    }
                }
            });
}

private void showNotification(int maxProgress) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, WorkoutService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notifyManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentTitle(getString(R
            .string.notification_title))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
    currentProgress = 0;
    builder.setProgress(maxProgress, currentProgress, false);
    notifyManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
}

private void sendMessageToActivity(Message message) {
    try {
        if (messenger != null) {
            messenger.send(message);
        }
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Timber.e(e, "Error sending message to activity");
    }
}

private void updateProgress() {
    currentProgress++;
    builder.setProgress(maxProgress, currentProgress, false);
    notifyManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
    Message message = Message.obtain(null, UPDATE_PROGRESS, currentProgress, 0);
    sendMessageToActivity(message);
}

}
```

The problem is the notification does not get dismissed while it should be and it seems the service does not get stopped even if I explicitly call stopSelf(). In the android documentation it says that this service stops himself when there is no longer work to be done but since I am calling onCompleted and unsubscribe should it not be the case? How can I make sure the observable stops emitting and the flow is terminated? Thks a lot

Comment: I can see lots of issues. You should use `takeWhile` to apply your boolean condition and *not* call `onCompleted` yourself, also after being completed you *are* unsubscribed, so there is no need to call that either. Also I don't think you should manually call `stopSelf` in use with intent services, but I could be wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is, your intent service already died when the onHandleIntent returned. 
IntentServices are a very special flavour of services that execute the onHandleIntent in a background thread and get dismissed.

By doing this, you are leaking that intentservice class because the subscriber holds a reference to it. When the subscription is done, you are calling stopSelf on a dead (leaked) service.

Moreover, there is no point in subscribing in a different thread since onHandleIntent is running in a different thread per se.

I think you should use a Service (not an intent one) to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: how can I do this

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to fedepaol and David Medenjak, I have managed to fix the problem.
by:

- Switching to service instead of intent service
- using takeWhile for the boolean condition

here is the resulting class

```
public class WorkoutService extends Service {
public static final String BUNDLE_EXTRA_MESSENGER = "messenger";
public static final String BUNDLE_EXTRA_NUMBER_ROUNDS = "nr_rounds";
public static final String BUNDLE_EXTRA_WORKOUT_DURATION = "workout_duration";
public static final String BUNDLE_EXTRA_PAUSE_DURATION = "pause_duration";
private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
public static final int UPDATE_PROGRESS = 2;

/**
 * Target we publish for clients to send messages to IncomingHandler.
 * This is the messenger from the activity
 */
Messenger messenger;

private NotificationManager notifyManager;
private NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
private volatile int maxProgress;
private int numberOfRounds = 4;
private int workoutDuration = 7 * 60; //7 minutes
private int pauseDuration = 90; //1.5 minutes
private int currentProgress;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        messenger = (Messenger) extras.get(BUNDLE_EXTRA_MESSENGER);
        numberOfRounds = extras.getInt(BUNDLE_EXTRA_NUMBER_ROUNDS, numberOfRounds);
        workoutDuration = extras.getInt(BUNDLE_EXTRA_WORKOUT_DURATION, workoutDuration);
        pauseDuration = extras.getInt(BUNDLE_EXTRA_PAUSE_DURATION, pauseDuration);
    }
    maxProgress = numberOfRounds * workoutDuration + ((numberOfRounds - 1) * pauseDuration);
    maxProgress = 10; //TODO: for testing
    showNotification(maxProgress);
    Timber.d("maxProgress %d", maxProgress);
    startWorkout();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


private void startWorkout() {
    final Observable<Long> observable = Observable
            .interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .takeWhile(new Func1<Long, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(Long aLong) {
                    return aLong <= maxProgress;
                }
            });
    observable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Long>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Timber.d("onCompleted");
                    stopForeground(true);
                    stopSelf();

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Timber.e("onError");
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Long aLong) {
                    Timber.d("onNext : " + aLong + "S");
                    updateProgress();
                }
            });
}

private void showNotification(int maxProgress) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, WorkoutService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notifyManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentTitle(getString(R
            .string.notification_title))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
    currentProgress = 0;
    builder.setProgress(maxProgress, currentProgress, false);
    notifyManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
}

private void sendMessageToActivity(Message message) {
    try {
        if (messenger != null) {
            messenger.send(message);
        }
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Timber.e(e, "Error sending message to activity");
    }
}

private void updateProgress() {
    currentProgress++;
    builder.setProgress(maxProgress, currentProgress, false);
    notifyManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
    Message message = Message.obtain(null, UPDATE_PROGRESS, currentProgress, 0);
    sendMessageToActivity(message);
}

}
```